When we use open_id for linkedin then what are the other configurations like template tag, authentication backend?
I am trying login with linkedin using Openid connect with django allauth but there is change in linkedin developers of signin using OpenId Connect any one know what are the configurations for this like template tag, redirect url, provider, please help me thanks in advance
I need latest configuration for login with linkedin using OpenId Connect in django allauth
